# GET and POST controller for one route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to have one route rule for both `GET` and `POST` methods that redirect to one controller. Problem is `GET` doesn't require any parameters (it returns a view) but `POST` will have some parameters that are sent through a form.

In ASP.NET MVC5 I do it with **one route rule** and **two controller methods with the same name** but one of them (the POST method) has a `[HttpPost]` attribute and the parameters it needs while the GET method doesn't have any parameter or attribute.

How does one implement something like that in Laravel 5.x?

This is the possible controller:

```
public function convertUrl($somedataforpost)
{
    if(Request::isMethod('get'))
    {
        // return a view
    }
    if(Request::isMethod('post'))
    {
        // do something with POST data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of how you would implement the rule:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'order/{invoice}/confirm', ['uses' => 'OrderController@paymentConfirmation', 'as' => 'order.payment.confirmation']);
```